# Pyomo KeyError when creating instance from data dictionary

Tags: python, pyomo

The `Set model.Power` should be indexed by `model.T`. As the code below shows, an abstract model is created and an instance will be created by loading data from a dictionary.

```
from pyomo.environ import *

model = AbstractModel()

model.T = Set(ordered=True)

#1: model.Power = Set(model.T)
model.Power = Set()

instance = model.create_instance(data={None: {
    'T': {None: [0,1,2,3]}, 
    'Power': {None: [0,900,1500,1800]} 
} })
```

The code works like this. But Power will not be indexed. When I uncomment the line #1 and comment the line below I get the following error.

```
KeyError: 'Cannot construct index None in array set Power'
```

No matter how I write the dictionary I cannot solve this.

How can I make sure that Power ist indexed by T and that I can create the instance from a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are running into the bug exactly, but if I run the code as such I am able to index properly:

```
from pyomo.core.base import AbstractModel, Set

model = AbstractModel()

model.T = Set(ordered=True)

#1: model.Power = Set(model.T)
model.Power = Set()

instance = model.create_instance(data={None: {
    'T': {None: [0,1,2,3]}, 
    'Power': {None: [0,900,1500,1800]} 
} })

print 'Printing T vals\n'
for k in instance.component('T'):
    print k

print '\nPrinting Power vals\n'

for k in instance.component('Power'):
    print k
```

output:

```
Printing T vals

0
1
2
3

Printing Power vals

0
1500
900
1800
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I run into this error when I want to make sure that Power is indexed by T. That's why i use the line `model.Power = Set(model.T)` and not `model.Power = Set()`. Sorry maybe I wasn't clear in the description.

Answer (score 0):

That's the solution:
Instead of trying to index a Set, I should have used an indexed Parameter, which was actually what I intended to do.

```
from pyomo.environ import *

model = AbstractModel()

model.T = Set(ordered=True)

model.Power = Param(model.T)

instance = model.create_instance(data={None: {
    'T': {None: [0,1,2,3]}, 
    'Power': {None: [0,900,1500,1800]} 
} })
```

Comment: nice! glad you solved it. Consider upvoting your own answer so others can find it easily.